# Lower and upper bound for the largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-matrices

We will call a matrix *positive matrix* if all elements in the matrix are positive, and we will denote the *largest eigenvalue* with $\lambda_{\max}$, what is exist because of the [Perron–Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a positive square matrix. Then the minimal row sum is a lower bound and the maximal row sum is an upper bound of $\lambda_{\max}$.

**My questions.**

1. Is there a name for this theorem and can anybody say books or papers what refer to it?
2. How to prove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us denote by $r$ the Perron-root of the positive matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then by the **Collatz-Wielandt formula** we have:

$$\max_{x \in S}\min_{\substack{i=1, \ldots,n}} \frac{(Ax)_i}{x_i} = r = \min_{x \in S}\max_{\substack{i=1, \ldots,n}} \frac{(Ax)_i}{x_i}, $$
where $S := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}: x_i > 0, \forall i=1,\ldots,n\}$. Now it is clear that $A$ and $A^T$ have same eigenvalues, since [$\det(M)=\det(M^T)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) and for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\det(A-\lambda I)=\det((A-\lambda I)^T)= \det(A^T-\lambda I).$$
Furthermore $A$ strictly positive implies $A^T$ strictly positive, thus this formula also holds for $A^T$. It follows that we have
$$\max_{x \in S}\min_{\substack{i=1, \ldots,n}} \frac{(A^Tx)_i}{x_i} = r = \min_{x \in S}\max_{\substack{i=1, \ldots,n}} \frac{(A^Tx)_i}{x_i}.$$
This clearly implies that for every $y \in S$ we have
$$\min_{\substack{i=1, \ldots,n}} \frac{(A^Ty)_i}{y_i} \leq  r \leq \max_{\substack{i=1, \ldots,n}} \frac{(A^Ty)_i}{y_i}.$$
Choose $y = (1,1,\ldots,1)$ to get your bounds. Note also that using the same trick on $A$ directly you will get the same upper/lower bound but with the columns instead of the rows.

For reference, I recommend (in increasing order of technicality/generality):

1. "Matrix analysis" by Horn and Johnson
2. "Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences" by Bermann and Plemmons
3. "Nonlinear Perron-Frobenius theory" by Nussbaum and Lemmens

There are even more general versions discussed in recent literature, e.g. in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/18M1165037)

Comment: Consider $A^T=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1  & 1\\ 4 & 1 & 1 \\ 5 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $y=(1, 0, 0)$. It can be checked that $r$ is greater than $5$, but $(A^Ty)_i/y_i=3$. The upper bound in the last inequality does not hold.

Comment: Please see item 7 of "positive matrices" in Section "Statements" in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron–Frobenius_theorem

Comment: In the reference you mentioned (I think you would refer to  "Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra" by Carl D. Meyer), as far as I could determine, the upper bounds are not stated.

Comment: Yes. But, in your answer, $S$ contains non-negative vectors.

Comment: @kswim looks like, 7 years ago, I did not realize the importance of the infimum (minimum), being taken on vectors in the interior of the cone. I corrected my answer, thanks for noting the mistake.

Comment: I found out that this led another questions about whether the formula is correct or not. So, I wanted to make things correct. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

See propositions 2.3 and 2.4 of the book "Banach Lattices and Positive operators" of H.H. Schaefer.

Comment: Can you maybe offer a good ebook version of it, or send me an image about the pages what you talking about? It could really help me.

Comment: Or just write it here.

Comment: See this link. http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GQ-oAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=row+sums. I could not find a better look inside this book. I forgot to say that the page is 7. The number $r(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$, which is the biggest positive eigenvalue for this type of matrix.